# AngularJS' ng:areq Bad Argument "{controller} is not a function", with textAngular on CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, codeigniter-3, textangular

I'm trying to implement a text editor with textAngular in a CodeIgniter view, but it keep returning this error:

```
angular.js:13424 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'wysiwygeditor' is not a function, got undefined
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/ng/areq?p0=wysiwygeditor&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
```

Where 'wysiwygeditor' is the name on `ng-controller`.

I've found tens of questions about that, and all seems to be caused by the same mistakes:

- Unnamed `ng-app` directive
- Omitted second argument on module    definition
  `angular.module('myApp', [])`
- Version incompatibilities on controller declaration

None of those happens to be the problem, and I'm simply copying a code that already works. It's the `demo.html` from [textAngular-1.5.0](http://textangular.com/). I copy the code to a CodeIgniter view, include all the [required](https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular/wiki/Getting-Started) libraries, but still get the error. Then I noticed it's happening whenever I declare a controller with Angular JS.

To make a better example:

```
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.min.js'></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="GreetingController">
        {{greeting}}
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

    myApp.controller('GreetingController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.greeting = 'Bom dia!';
    }]);
</script>
```

This code gives that error on CodeIgniter, but if I put it in a simple html file, works normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fault, my project was declaring an `ng-app` on a parent element, in a template file that I've forgot that existed. Removed this tag, and AngularJS stop returning that error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your edited working code...
Dont use editor, Its waste of your time, They are mostly not working , some time its working...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" >
<div ng-controller="GreetingController">
{{greeting}}
</div>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('GreetingController', function($scope) {
    $scope.greeting= "John";

});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not using an editor, I'm trying to implement an text editor to my client. My problem is that I can't manage to declare an Angular JS controller in a CodeIgniter View, and make it work.